# How to get database IP address, Port no in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle11g, database-administration

I am a first time user to Oracle database. Today I installed the oracle according to a tutorial. But I was not able to copy the REPOSITORY_URL given at the end of the installation. Please tell me is there a way to recover it ?
Or I will have to install it again. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To get the URL of REPOSITORY_URL, follow the below given steps. You donot need to reinstall instance

1] Go to $AGENT_HOME/sysman/config and open emd.properties

2] Find REPOSITORY_URL=https://host:1159/em/upload

Comment: My OS is Window. Sorry for not mentioning earlier.